# Where can I set the BufferColor property for labels in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, layouts

The accepted answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31478/what-are-valid-values-for-data-defined-labeling-settings) suggests that the buffer color can be set as a data defined label property. However, in the Layer Properties > Labels > Advanced tab, the only options I can see for the buffer are size and transparency. How can I set the BufferColor property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a separate labelling method found under the Layer menu (NOT from the layer properties).  Use this instead of the normal labeling you get from the layer properties menu.

Go to: Layer->Labelling and then click on the 'Data defined settings' tab.  Scroll to just over halfway down.  To use this you need to set values in your attribute table.

Comment: Found this seconds before I read your answer - thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not in the `Advanced` Tab, it's in the `Data defined settings` tab:

```
Layer Properties > Labels > Data defined settings > Buffer
```

[image: Set buffer color.]

*(At least in QGIS 1.9.0-master.)*

Comment: This isn't in 1.8 Lisboa - sorry, I should have specified my version.