# Where can I find a list of valid settings for expanded data defined labeling?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have seen this post [What are valid values for "data defined" labeling settings?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31478/what-are-valid-values-for-data-defined-labeling-settings). Does anyone have any insight to the values within attribute tables required to satify the expanded "Data defined settings' in the labeling dialogue box. I am using 1.9

Comment: The answer you linked seems pretty thorough. Which information are you missing?

Comment: There are a number of others, e.g. show labels, bold, word spacing, etc. where is this information? You all are able to find it, but with no avail, Google search comes up empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry @LandArch, but those new data defined settings are not yet documented in an organized manner. More data defined settings will be added before the 2.0 release. When the feature freeze for 2.0 comes down, I will be trying to fully document all of the changes to the new generation labeling engine before the string freeze happens, approximately a month later.

In the meantime, and since things are going to be in flux for at least the next month, your best bet is to read the comments in the [QgsPalLayerSettings declaration](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/src/core/qgspallabeling.h#L59) and parse the [logic in its definition](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/src/core/qgspallabeling.cpp#L190), then contrast that with how the GUI for those settings is designed and [the other referenced answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31478).

Comment: It looks like I am getting ahead of myself. Sorry about that, I am just excited about the advances that are in the works with QGIS. As always I appreciate everyone time, especially since I am learning GIS on my own with the insight of the community.